# passing a parameter from a content type to a module

Tags: twig, drupal-8, twig-extension

I assumed this would be easy but I am stumped.

I have a custom content type that includes an id field. I render these with a basic page template.

I have written a small module that creates a block which is populated with data from an external API. Everything works except I cannot seem to figure out how to pass the value of the id from the content of a given page to my module so it can make the API call.

It would be a couple of lines of code in straight php, it can't be that complicated in Drupal 8 and twig can it?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204851/how-to-access-field-values-from-a-custom-block/204865?noredirect=1#comment249205_204865)

I am re-posting it in case it is useful to anyone else.

If you are generating a custom block you can access content fields via the routing system inside your block build function like this:

```
public function build() {

    if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
      $field_my_custom_value = $node->field_my_custom_value->value;
    }

    //do something with the variable, like make the API call

    //Make sure to set the cache to the context or even to zero if you need
    return array(
      '#markup' => $this->t('my content to render'),
      '#cache' => array(
         'contexts' => ['contexts' => ['route']],
      ),
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can reach what you want with a HOOK_preprocess.

use:

```
YOUR_MODULE_preprocess_node(&$variables){ ... } or
YOUR_MODULE_preprocess_block(&$variables){ ... }
```

to access your variable from the content type and pass it to your function oder template.

Comment: Any examples? The only ones I can find pass variables from the module back to the template. I need to pass it the other way first.